# исчезают элементы айтема при прокрутке recyclerview

Tags: java, android

Когда докручиваю до конца списка, у первых двух элементов пропадают два Textview, но все остальные части айтема остаются заполнены. В чём может быть причина?

Код адаптера:

```
package com.difl.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.difl.myapplication.DB.MyDbManager;
import com.difl.myapplication.dbkosh.MyDbManagerCosh;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyHolder> {

    private static List<com.difl.myapplication.Model.Product> productList;
    private final Context context;
    private MyDbManager myDbManager;
    private MyDbManagerCosh myDbManagerCosh;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<com.difl.myapplication.Model.Product> productList) {
        Adapter.productList = productList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.title_txt.setText(productList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.rold.setText(productList.get(position).getPrice().toString() + " ₴");
        holder.only.setText(productList.get(position).getPrice().toString() + " ₴");
        holder.price_txt.setText(productList.get(position).getPriceOld().toString() + " ₴");
        holder.procent.setText(productList.get(position).getCount().toString() + " %");
        Picasso.get().load(productList.get(position).getImages().get(0)).into(holder.img);

        holder.price_txt.setPaintFlags(holder.price_txt.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        if (productList.get(position).getPriceOld().toString().equals("0")){
            holder.only.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.price_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.rold.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            holder.only.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }      
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView img, limg;
        TextView title_txt, price_txt, procent, rold, proccent, only;
        ImageButton opnkosh_bt, likee_bt;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            limg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.limg);
            procent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.procent);
            title_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_txt);
            price_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_txt);
            rold = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rold);
            opnkosh_bt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.opnkosh_bt);
            likee_bt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likee_bt);
            only = itemView.findViewById(R.id.only);

        }
    }

    public void filterListthis(List<com.difl.myapplication.Model.Product> lostlist){

        productList = lostlist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecyclerView` переиспользует `ViewHolder` и `View`. При одном item вы в `if` убрали видимость, при другом item в `else` не восстановили